# plot trade entry signals on a price graph of tick data

Tags: r, graph, gnuplot

I have tick time series data and want to plot a price graph and overlay on it the trade entry and exit points so I can see visually how my trading algorithm is performing.
Does R graphing have this overlay capabilities, or does one need to use gnuplot. Are there any examples anyone can refer me to....thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can easily do this in R.  See `?points`.